# How to downgrade conda version?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I need to downgrade my conda version from 4.3  to 4.2 on my CentOS 6.7 machine.
What is the command required to do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend downgrading `conda` except when the newly installed (upgraded) version has a critical bug.

But since you asked: You can specify a version by appending `={version}` to the packages, this works even for the `conda` package:

```
$ conda install conda=4.2
```

If you want a specific `4.2` version you can also use (for example):

```
$ conda install conda=4.2.15
```

Note that downgrading conda can be very risky. After the downgrade your `conda` could fail completely or work incorrectly. Conda uses a lot of metadata that evolve over time ... so if the downgraded conda version cannot make sense of these - or even worse corrupt them - you'll have a painful experience in how to recover your conda environemnt. **Downgrade conda at your own risk** (and in my opinion only if **really, really** necessary)!

---

In case you already downgraded `conda` and it's throwing exceptions (for example `CondaUpgradeError`) at you, then maybe this "section" in an [troubleshooting guide in the conda repository](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/docs/source/user-guide/troubleshooting.rst#conda-upgrade-error) may be useful:

> ### Conda upgrade error
>
> #### Cause
>
> Downgrading conda from 4.6.1 to 4.5.x and then trying to `conda install conda` or `conda upgrade conda` will produce a solving and upgrade error similar to the following:
>
> ```
> Solving environment: failed
> CondaUpgradeError: This environment has previously been operated on by a
> conda version that's newer than the conda currently being used. A newer
> version of conda is required.
> target environment location: /opt/conda
> current conda version: 4.5.9
> minimum conda version: 4.6
> ```
>
> #### Solution
>
> Change the .condarc file. Set the parameter by editing the .condarc file directly: `allow_conda_downgrades: true` in conda version 4.5.12. This will then let you upgrade. If you have something older than 4.5.12, install conda 4.6.1 again from the package cache.
>
> EXAMPLE: If my `conda info` says `package cache : /opt/conda/pkgs` and my Python version is 3.7, then on the command line, type `conda install /opt/conda/pkgs/conda-4.6.1-py37_0.tar.bz2` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Careful!  I used this to downgrade from 4.6.2 to 4.5.12 and I am now stuck with the following error: `CondaUpgradeError: This environment has previously been operated on by a conda version that's newer
than the conda currently being used. A newer version of conda is required.`

Comment: @Selah Thank you for the comment. I actually updated the answer to include (lots of) warnings that downgrading conda can be very risky. However for your particular case I found a section in the conda troubleshooting guide that may apply. Since this could be useful for future readers I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you!!  FYI - I asked a question based on that comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542706/how-can-i-get-unstuck-from-condaupgradeerror-a-newer-version-of-conda-is-requir . Feel free to answer if you'd like the points!

Comment: I updated to conda 22.9.0 and this turned to be very buggy so I did `conda install conda=4.14` to go back to the previous version and it was super smooth with zero issues.