# How can I get unstuck from CondaUpgradeError "A newer version of conda is required."?

Tags: python, conda

I attempted to downgrade my conda version.  With conda at version 4.6.2, I ran `conda install conda=4.5.12`.  I then went to run other conda commands, but was met with the following error:

```
CondaUpgradeError: This environment has previously been operated on by a conda version that's newer
than the conda currently being used. A newer version of conda is required.
  target environment location: /home/selah/anaconda3
  current conda version: 4.5.12
  minimum conda version: 4.6
```

I am now stuck and unable to successfully run any conda commands.  How can I get conda back in working order again?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The conda documentation explicitly mentions this issue in their ["Troubleshooting" documentation](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/docs/source/user-guide/troubleshooting.rst#conda-upgrade-error)

> ### Conda upgrade error
>
> #### Cause
>
> Downgrading conda from 4.6.1 to 4.5.x and then trying to `conda install conda` or `conda upgrade conda` will produce a solving and upgrade error similar to the following:
>
> ```
> Solving environment: failed
> CondaUpgradeError: This environment has previously been operated on by a
> conda version that's newer than the conda currently being used. A newer
> version of conda is required.
> target environment location: /opt/conda
> current conda version: 4.5.9
> minimum conda version: 4.6
> ```
>
> #### Solution
>
> Change the .condarc file. Set the parameter by editing the .condarc file directly: `allow_conda_downgrades: true` in conda version 4.5.12. This will then let you upgrade. If you have something older than 4.5.12, install conda 4.6.1 again from the package cache.
>
> EXAMPLE: If my `conda info` says `package cache : /opt/conda/pkgs` and my Python version is 3.7, then on the command line, type `conda install /opt/conda/pkgs/conda-4.6.1-py37_0.tar.bz2` to resolve the issue.

This should already provide enough information to at least try to recover from that problem. I decided to add a few additional informations and to rephrase it in my own words:

### Solution if you downgraded to 4.5.12

Since you installed 4.5.12 you should be able to simply modify the `.condarc` file and include (or change) `allow_conda_downgrades: true`.

The documentation ["Using the .condarc conda configuration file"](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#overview) provides the possible locations for the `.condarc` file:

> The `.condarc` file **is not included by default**, but it is automatically created in **your home directory** the first time you run the `conda config` command.
>
> A `.condarc` file may also be located in the **root environment**, in which case it overrides any in the home directory.

Then update to 4.6 again (or whatever version you had previously):

```
conda install conda=4.6.2
```

Then change the setting in the `.condarc` file back to false:

```
allow_conda_downgrades: false
```

The last step is optional but I think the default is `false` to protect users from metadata-corruption by old conda versions. So I would change it back after recovering from the exception.

### Solution if you downgraded to 4.5.x where x is smaller than 12 (or the above did not work)

If that doesn't work or you had downgraded to an earlier version of `conda` 4.5.x then you have to use the other approach. Run:

```
conda info
```

Search for the line that starts with `package cache :`. Navigate to that directory and look for `conda....tar.gz.bz2` files. Select the one that you had previously installed and then run:

```
conda install PATH  # <- replace the PATH with the actual path to the selected conda file
```

Note that you can also download the file from [the anaconda channel directly](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda/files) and then provide the path to this downloaded file.

### Last Resort (if you're desperate and nothing worked)

In case that did not work you could try brute-force approaches. Although be warned that they could do **even more damage** to your conda setup - treat them as last resort (e.g. when you consider uninstalling and reinstalling conda/anaconda).

For example you could also try to manually "install" it over the existing installation (again: this may not work and maybe you cannot undo this step again!):

- Use the conda "tar.gz.bz2" file found by the previous step (or if you don't have it download it from the anaconda channel: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda/files)
- Extract it into your root environment replacing existing files.
- Hope!
- Hope!
- Test if it worked

Comment: Thanks, I located config with: 'conda config --show-sources', on Ubuntu, added 'allow_conda_downgrades: false' and then ' conda update -n base -c defaults conda'

Answer (score 6):

I really struggled with this issue.
All the solutions here did not work for me. This is what works for me:

- Find the `/conda-meta/history` file in the root. (Multile Locations)
- Delete or rename it,
- Then `conda update conda`.

To help local this folder on mac you can use: mdfind kind:folder "conda-meta"

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, I used Isaacsh's solution:

[https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1757](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1757#issuecomment-152619715)

to create the .condarc file inside my `c:\users\<username>` folder. I then added 
   `allow_conda_downgrades: true` using Notebook

At the Anaconda Prompt, I entered  `conda install conda=4.6` and it installed version 4.6.3

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, if you have Anaconda Navigator installed, open it and update the conda version there from the GUI.

[image: Update Conda]