# CondaUpgradeError: This environment has previously been operated on by a conda version that's newer

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I was trying to fix an issue with an old environment earlier today and screwed up `conda`. I get this:

```
Solving environment: failed

CondaUpgradeError: This environment has previously been operated on by a conda version that's newer
than the conda currently being used. A newer version of conda is required.
  target environment location: /Users/U6020643/anaconda3
  current conda version: 4.5.11
  minimum conda version: 4.8
```

**The original problem:** I recently upgraded to Catalina, and could not build Pandas when installing it to recreate an environment.

**Rehoming:** Was this post regarding [How to Restore Anaconda after Update to MacOS Catalina](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update). I downloaded the script and ran it. It appeared to work. But I had the same problem with Pandas.

```
./cpr rehome ~/anaconda3
```

**Installing a revision**: At some point in my debugging I also ran this, which I have a hunch caused the problem.

```
conda install --revision 0
```

**Trying to install Conda 4.8**: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542706/how-can-i-get-unstuck-from-condaupgradeerror-a-newer-version-of-conda-is-requir) post and attempted the accepted solution.

I added `allow_conda_downgrades: true` to my `~/.condarc` file. `conda update conda` produced the same `CondaUpgradeError` and so did `conda install conda==4.8.1`.

Next I found the package-cache via `conda info` and attempted to install 4.8 from there. Here is my `conda info` output.

```
     active environment : None
       user config file : /Users/me/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/me/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : 3.15.1
         python version : 3.7.0.final.0
       base environment : /Users/me/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /Users/me/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/me/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/me/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/me/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.0 Darwin/19.6.0 OSX/10.15.6
                UID:GID : 502:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Then I downloaded `osx-64/conda-4.8.3-py37_0.tar.bz2` from Anaconda [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda/files), put it into `/Users/me/anaconda3/pkgs/`, and tried:

```
conda install /Users/me/anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.8.3-py37_0.tar.bz2
```

Which resulted in this issue, where I continue to be stuck.

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'conda-package-handling' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

**Before marking as duplicate:** consider carefully the similar posts. The version numbers here are different, the path and circumstances that resulted in this problem are different, and I have attempted those solutions without luck.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Conda, as recommended in [the blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update) ?

Answer (score 0):

## Standalone Conda

I would try downloading a standalone version of Conda that matches the old version of Conda you had (something in v4.8.x), and then try using this to upgrade the Conda package in the **base** env.

I don't know for sure this will work, but it is pretty simple and will not change anything unless it does work.

#### Downloads

You can download builds of `conda-standalone` (PyInstaller-based binaries) from either the [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda-standalone/files) or [Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/conda-standalone/files) channel. Browse to your version (or something close), download the archive (to wherever), unzip, and in the folder `standalone_conda` you will find a `conda.exe` file, which is the binary you'll need.

#### Configuration

Next, you need to set the environment variable `CONDA_ROOT_PREFIX` to point to your **base** env's folder, which from your output is `/Users/me/anaconda3/`. So,

```
export CONDA_ROOT_PREFIX=/Users/me/anaconda3
```

Then, to test, check

```
./conda.exe info
```

and verify that the values for `base environment:`, `package cache:`, and `envs directories` point to the correct locations, which in a default install would be `/Users/me/anaconda3`, `/Users/me/anaconda3/pkgs`, and `/Users/me/anaconda3/envs`, respectively.

#### Upgrade

Attempt upgrading the `conda` package in the **base** env:

```
./conda.exe upgrade -n base -c defaults conda
```

Hopefully, the error you reported before doesn't recur, but I'm actually not sure. Make sure to review any changes if the solve does work.

In the end you can discard the `conda.exe` and go back to using the one in **base**.